# Difference between "looked like" and "were looking like"

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, sentence-choice

1) Why past tense has been used in below sentence for looked, walked?

2) Can we use my version of sentence using *looking*, *walking*?

a) Actual...

> *The video was shot beautifully. Pranay Kumar and Amruta Varshini **looked like** movie stars. They were in love and the camera seemed to celebrate that. Resplendent and happy, as the young couple **walked** around Hidden Castle near Siddipet, 80km from Hyderabad, it felt like they were on a film set in Scotland .*

b) My Version...

> *The video was shot beautifully. Pranay Kumar and Amruta Varshini **were looking like** movie stars. They were in love and the camera seemed to celebrate that. Resplendent and happy, as the young couple **walking** around Hidden Castle near Siddipet, 80km from Hyderabad, it felt like they were on a film set in Scotland .*

Comment: In this context, no difference whatsoever. Just I'd add *...the young couple **were** walking around...*

Answer (score -1):

I your sentence you have written **were looking** instead of **looked**. Since you have added the word "were", it automatically becomes a past tense(past participle/past continuous or something like that,am not sure :P ), so its the correct usage in that sentence. But in your 2nd sentence **"walking around Hidden.."** , that is grammatically wrong, you cant use a present continuous tense for something that has already happened.